# Firefox search OR operator

Tags: find, firefox

Does firefox search have an OR operator ... find "Ann" OR "Mary" ?

A plugin would also be an alternative, but I haven't been able to find any that does something similar.

Comment: Do you mean a search *in* Firefox of a webpage you're visiting or a search engine you've visited *with* Firefox? If you mean searches in Firefox, I don't think you can do this, but there may be a plugin (none leap to mind).

Comment: I mean ... uhmm, Ctrl-F search. Sorry, thought it was clear enough :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Google search plugin on your Firefox,

> "Ann" OR "Mary"

should work.

<sup>It will also work at the [Google search page](http://www.google.com/search?q=Ann+OR+Mary) directly.</sup>

---

If you are referring to the Firefox Quickfind (at the bottom of the window),
I think there are just two controls to reach it -- the '`/`' and the '`'`'.
They can be reprogrammed (to use different keys), but further things are not supported.
Here is a [Mozilla KB article on that](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Quick+find+bar+opens+when+typing+in+text+fields).
Would like to know if other operators can work with the Quickfind.

---

There are [a few addons for the find bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/Find%20Bar) -- but mostly for cosmetics.
<sup>The firefox findbar is quite integrated -- [firefox XUL findbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/findbar) ref</sup>

Comment: Or in fact any search plugin. They all operate on the same principles (of course someone will now prove me wrong).

Comment: I half wonder if he means `CTRL-F`: searches of a page's content in Firefox. In which case, I think that the answer is "No."

Comment: @Telemachus - exactly. I thought it was clear under "firefox search" ... while this is "google search" or whatever other.